# Typescript is making me pass an id even though it is a bigserial and it should increment by itself

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, bigint, prisma2

I am using Prisma 2 as my ORM and it is generating a typescript type for me along with the migration. The problem is that the id field (with the @id decorator) has to be required and so that translates into TS and the compiler makes me pass in the id. But the id is a bigint and so it should increment itself. I have already tried altering the type manually but then I have to rewrite it every time i migrate. I already have the same schema on one other model and that works just fine. I can't seem to figure out why

my schema.prisma User model:

```
model User {
  id            Int     @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  first_name    String   @db.VarChar(20)
  middle_name   String?  @db.VarChar(20)
  last_name     String   @db.VarChar(50)
  email         String?  @db.VarChar(50)
  date_of_birth DateTime @db.Date
  posts         Post[]
  password      String
  sessionSecret String 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and realised it was caused by using the wrong types. I had a user model with

```
id            Int        @id(map: "mood_pk") @default(autoincrement())
```

which results in a `User` type with

```
id: number,
```

however when calling `prisma.user.create({data: newUser})`, the `newUser` object should not be typed with `User`, it should be typed with `Prisma.userCreateInput`, which does not require that a number is passed to the `id` prop.

Just adding this here in case it helps anyone else, and for next time I forget this and run into the same issue...

Answer (score -1):

The Prisma types are generating exactly what the Model has defined in it.  The model has `id` as required, so the generated type has the `id` property required.

You have two simple options around this.  Modify the Prisma type to make the `id` optional, or create a second TypeScript interface with an optional `id` or without the `id` property.

Option One

Based on the docs, https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference/#-modifier-1, the modified Prisma type would look like this,

```
model User {
  id?            Int     @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  ...rest of the model
```

Option Two

If the existing TypeScript interface is this,

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  ...rest of the interface
}
```

then your modified TypeScript interface without the `id` property could be,

```
interface NewUser extends Omit<User, 'id'> {}
```

Or with an optional `id` property,

```
interface NewUser extends Omit<User, 'id'> {
  id?: number;
}
```

Comment: i dont know what any of that entity stuff means but thanks, so you are basically saying its a feature not a bug ?

Comment: oh and as i said you cant make an id field optional

Comment: Before you create a User, you don't have an id.  So at this point and time, the is either optional or doesn't exist on the User model.  So, you either need a separate typescript type for this or you need to make the id optional in the Prisma model.
An entity is basically just your model.  It's like a record in the database.

Comment: I updated the answer to try and make it clearer.

Comment: see the thing is you can't just make the id optional because that is just prohibited by Prisma. I got it working by making a new typescript interface but I dunno it just feels like a workaround because in that case the generated types just lose their whole purpose.